# Changing useState in TextInput will cause the keyboard to retract

Tags: react-native, textinput

Changing the useState using onChangeText in TextInput in ReactNative will cause the keyboard to retract

I have tried using 'useCallback' or 'onEndEditing', but there is no way to solve them. I hope everyone can find a solution

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that when I use component methods, I have problems.
This is my code

```
 const rightCom=()=>{
        if (listNum ===0)return  <OcAvatar/>;
        if (listNum ===2)return  <IntimacyFn/>;
        if (listNum ===3)return  <OcSkin/>;

        if (listNum>3)return <OcCustom/>
    }

<View className='p-3'>
 {rightCom()}
</View>


    const [localValueFirst, setLocalValueFirst] = useState('');
    const handleChangeText = (text)=>{
   setLocalValueFirst(text)
}


 <TextInput
   maxLength={3}  
    value={localValueFirst}
    onChangeText={handleChangeText}/>
```

When I don't use component mode, there's no problem。This is strange

```
 <View className='p-3'>
    {listNum === 1 ? 
      <View>
        <TextInput
            maxLength={3}  
             value={localValueFirst}
             onChangeText={handleChangeText}/>
     </View>
      :null}

</View>
```